# ¿Cómo enviar un email automáticamente cuando se active una consulta SQL que devuelva una fecha de vencimiento, por medio de PHP?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli, aplicación-web, email

La siguiente consulta me avisa cuando los documentos están próximos a vencer

```
sql=SELECT v.id, v.veh_placa, d.doc_date_ex, d.doc_date_ven
FROM  documents d 
INNER JOIN vehicles v 
  ON d.vehicles_id = v.id 
INNER JOIN typesdoc t 
  ON t.id = d.typesdoc_id 
WHERE doc_date_ven BETWEEN CURDATE( ) AND DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Pero quiero que se ejecute automáticamente esta consulta, para cuando obtenga resultados de los documentos a vencer se envíe al administrador un correo mostrando los resultados de esta consulta.

El sistema esta realizado en PHP con MySQLi y para el envío de correos con PHPMAILER.

Pero no tengo idea de cómo realizar esta ejecución de enviar automáticamente el correo apenas se active la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que estas corriendo sobre unix y tienes acceso a la maquina.

Haremos un CronJob que corra todos los dias a las 2am (hora del servidor) que ejecute el un php, por lo tanto necesitas crear el php que execute la consulta que planteas y envie los correos.

primero abrimos la crontab con:

```
crontab -e
```

despues creamos el cron que ejecutara tu php

```
0 2 * * * /usr/bin/php -q /ruta/a/tu/archivo.php
```

y por ultimo reiniciamos los servicios

```
service crond restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer este tipo de "automatizaciones", debes tener acceso a tu servidor, praa poder programar tareas.

Estas tareas son las llamadas `cron`. Hasta donde yo lo he probado, se crea el fichero PHP, llamado `cron.php` y configuras la tarea en el servidor.

Otra forma de hacerlo en mediante CURL, pero no lo he usado nunca